# How to make link to new page trigger action on that new page on load

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, triggers

I have a portfolio grid on one page with 3 filters based on client type.

I would love to have 3 links on my homepage, each linking to the same portfolio page, but trigger a spicifc filter type based on what link was clicked from the homepage.

Ie: If I click the "Architects" link on the homepage, it will open the portfolio page and activate the "Architects" filter.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TUbn.png)

I've tried to google a solution for the past hours, but most seem to only trigger the same script on page load and is not based on the link used to get to the site.

Ie a specific link will trigger a specific script. If none of the links are used. Nothing will trigger.

I'm way in over my head here as this is my first website and trying out WP just with a bought theme.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Had a friend try his luck with it. Nothing works though.

He says:
*Part of the problem is that your theme is using a very old version of MixItUp. I confirmed that those are the proper commands, but I can't find a good place to hook into them because the old version of MixItUp the theme uses doesn't send out any events. It does have callback functions at certain points, but the theme is already using them for other things.*

```
if (window.location.hash == 'architects') {
    $j('.projects_holder').mixitup('filter', 'portfolio_category_452');
}

if (window.location.hash == 'designers') {
    $j('.projects_holder').mixitup('filter', 'portfolio_category_454');
}

if (window.location.hash == 'developers') {
    $j('.projects_holder').mixitup('filter', 'portfolio_category_456');
}
```

He suggested:

*The only thing I can think to do is hack around it with a delay. This code might work, but's not the best solution:*

```
setTimeout(function () {
    if (window.location.hash == 'architects') {
        $j('.projects_holder').mixitup('filter', 'portfolio_category_452');
    }

    if (window.location.hash == 'designers') {
        $j('.projects_holder').mixitup('filter', 'portfolio_category_454');
    }

    if (window.location.hash == 'developers') {
        $j('.projects_holder').mixitup('filter', 'portfolio_category_456');
    }   
}, 1500);
```

No luck either...

Any way, hoping some one else might stumble upon this and find some of it usefull.

Comment: There's not really enough information to go on, but you could use GET parameters. So one link might be `example.com/portfolio?filter=architect` and another might be `example.com/portfolio?filter=designer`.

Comment: Just a general question. Why don't you use the wordpress categories? Nice URL, easy link in the menu?

Comment: thank you @helgatheviking I've tried different variants of adding the "?filter=xxxx" to my buttons link. But I just get a 404. 
Searched some more and I'm not sure if I have to add something to my functions.php file for WP to accept these URLs... 
As you can hear, this is not my specialty. Any information I should add for my question?

Comment: There's not a lot we'll be able to do without knowing more about the theme. You might be better served by hiring someone to do the customization for you. If you are getting 404s it's always worth resaving your permalinks. Settings>Permalinks>save.

Comment: @helgatheviking the 404s was due to my page still being in draft mode. Nothing really happens when I try adding different variations of the "?filter" line to my URL.

Yeah, I think you might be right. Its a bought theme from Select called Brick. But they don't do custom work. Is there a job board small tasks like this here or where is a good place to go?

Comment: Well the "?filter" was a suggested approach, you need to wire up the part that processes that passed variable to display. I've heard upwork.com is a decent place for small gigs.